# How to simplify this function in Vuex

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

i need some way to simplify this async call, where I can return snapshot as an array without having to create an array like the one in the example? Thank you

Edit: The async call in the following example works correctly but I want to simplify that call without declaring an array.

```
  actions: {
    getUsers: async function({ commit }) {
      try {
        const snapshot = await db.collection("users").get()
        var array = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          array.push(doc.data());
        });
        commit("loadUsers", array);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },
```

> Example: commit("loadUsers", snapshot );

Comment: Whether there should be try..catch depends on your case. Is it desirable for a caller to dispatch an action and don't know if it was successful?

Comment: I'll fix it later, I just put it for the example of the question raised

Answer (score 1):

`snapshot` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) type object.  Since it exposes the resulting documents in an array type field called [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs), you can use that to create an array of objects of data from each document:

```
const array = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
commit("loadUsers", array);
```

It's not really any more efficient, though.  They are roughly equivalent bits of code.

Comment: This example works, thanks. But a question. Something like the following?  const snapshot = await db.collection("users").get().then(function() {
          return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        });
        commit("loadUsers", snapshot);

Comment: neither in this way .then(function() {
            return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
          }).then(
            commit("loadUsers", snapshot)
          )

Comment: @RipperNoChart That's because `snapshot` is assigned after you're trying to access it in `then`. Just don't use `then` together with `async`. `async..await` is syntactic sugar for `then` that is supposed to replace it.

Comment: I I'm kind to I'm jump iinioompluklojkjk to ijjill.  ... Pp